# Git add unchanged files to be commited

Tags: git, github

I just created a personal Github account and want to commit specific files to it from my Ruby on Rails application.

Currently my Application has a company repository, I want to do a ONE TIME commit to my personal repository.

For example, I want to commit my images_controller.rb to my personal repository. It is not changed nor do I want to change it.

I have tried `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged app/controllers/grandstreamers/images_controller.rb` then adding it. It does not stage.

How do I add specific files to stage for a commit? Thank you

Comment: If the file is not changed, why are you trying to commit it?

Comment: have you tried the `git add` command?

Comment: I want my personal repository to have some sample files since this is the new resume, to have a Github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git tracks files in the whole folder. From your question, I assume your local git repo includes all the files - and remote is a "work" remote, and you want to have a single file from that repo in your personal github account.

To do that, copy your file of choice (`images_controller.rb`) to a separate folder, then in that new folder, init a new git repo:

`git init`

Then add your github repo as a remote

`git add remote origin git@github.com:your_github_name/your_repo_name.git`

Then add your file -

`git add .`

Commit -

`git commit -m 'commit message'`

And push

`git push origin master`

Tadaa! You should have your file on github now.

Comment: This is a solution, I just thought Git would have a easy way to push a couple files to a seperate repository.

Comment: Well, git tracks the changes of all files that had been added to the repo... I suppose as a quickie you could also init a new repo in `app/controllers`, and add that individual file, then add remote, and after pushing to your github remote just removed `.git` directory from `/controllers/`... but what if there's another file you want to keep? Or what if there are updates? If you have it in your own separate folder, you can add more stuff and just commit and push again with no extra pain ;)

Comment: I am going to copy the files do a different directory with my personal Github account. +1 Thinking out of the box, atleast for me :D

Answer (score 1):

If by *"unchanged"* you mean *"the file is already in the repo and I'm trying to add/commit it again"*, then the answer is: no, you can't and don't need to do that. The file is already part of the repo, so there is no additional information that git is able to add. For that reason, it won't stage the file.
If you want to mark the existing file for a particular purpose, consider using `git tag` instead.

If by *"unchanged"* you mean *"the file exists in a different repo/location and I want to add it to a new repo, without editing it"*, then make sure your current directory is under the repo you want to add the file to, and that the file is also inside the new repo's main directory (in a subdirectory of the same path is fine). Then you should be able to `git add` the file.

Comment: +1 I think this answer is similar to apprenticeDev's, but I don't really follow.

Answer (score 0):

If git won't include the file you want, remove the file through git, commit, then revert the commit: the file will be included.

```
$ git rm recommit_this_file
$ git commit -m "Revert this commit."
$ git revert HEAD
```

It's not always enough to "force" git to do what you want. To make it actually behave the way you want, sometimes you have to trick it, too.